# Laravel, borrar automaticamente los datos creados para tests una vez finalizados estos

Tags: laravel, test, phpunit

estoy haciendo unos testeos de un crud:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\Model3D;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Tests\TestCase;

class Model3DCrudTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testStore()
    {
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        Auth::login($user);
        
        $data = [
            'title'=>'title test',
            'description'=>'description test',
            'file_name'=>'file name test'
        ];

        $response = $this->post('/model',$data);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Lo que pasa es que cuando se pasan las pruebas no hace ningun tipo de rolback de estos datos dummys que se crean. Cual seria la forma correcta ?

Answer (score 1):

Justamente he encontrado ahora mismo la respuesta:

El tema es que hay que convertir de alguna manera el test en una transacción, se hace usando este **trait** dentro de la clase de testing:

```
 use DatabaseTransactions;
```

De esta forma sabrá laravel que una ves han terminado los testeos debe resetear el modelo al estado anterior a este.

Espero ayudar a alguien con esta pequeña aportación.